# View engine does not render the view when I pass a model from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rendering, viewengine

I am developing an **MVC3** application using **C# and Razor**. I have a problem when I need to display one the Play View.

The **Play action method** is used to retrieve a path of a **FLV (Flash)** file to be then passed to the **Play View** to reproduce the file.
When I use `return View("Play")` the application renders the View **correctly**. However I need to pass the path variable to the View as shown in the code. When I do it I receive the following message:

**The view 'Play' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations**

Here is the **Action Method**:

```
public ActionResult Play(int topicId)
{
var ltopicDownloadLink = _webinarService.FindTopicDownloadLink(topicId);

if (ltopicDownloadLink != null)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebinarRecordings/" + ltopicDownloadLink);
    var file = new FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        return View("Play", path);
    }
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the **Play View**:

```
@model System.String

<div id='player'>This div will be replaced by the JW Player.</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/FLV Player/jwplayer.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

   var filepath = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

   jwplayer('player').setup({
   'flashplayer':'/FLV Player/player.swf',
   'width': '400',
   'height': '300',
   'file': filepath
   });
</script>
```

My only hint is that I make some mistake in using the model in the javascript. May you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Seeing that the error message is about the Index view, doesn't that make the Play view irrelevant to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking a [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743.aspx). Here's the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx):

```
return View("Play", (object)path);
```

or you could also declare the `path` variable as object:

```
object path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebinarRecordings/" + ltopicDownloadLink);
```

and then

```
return View("Play", path);
```

will also work:

Answer (score 1):

You should cast your model to object `return View("Play", (object)path);`, otherwise method where second parameter is path to master page is called

Answer (score 1):

View is overloaded in a way that if you pass a string (with static type string) into it, it will land in the wrong overload

You want this overload:

```
View(String, Object)    Creates a ViewResult object by using the view name and model that renders a view to the response.
```

And that's the overload you actually called:

```
View(String, String)        Creates a ViewResult object using the view name and master-page name that renders a view to the response.
```

So it thought that your model is the name of the master-page. The workaround is making the static type of the model you pass in something other than string:

```
View("viewname",(object)model)
```

No idea why the developers thought that overloading `View` in such an ambiguous way is a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you need an Index action in your Controller.

The error is about the Index action missing, not about the Play view. Try implementing an Index action and see what happens.

Comment: sorry my bad. I edited the text, I have indeed an Index action in my controller but it is not relevant in the context of this issue